# Pyspark remove duplicates base 2 columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the next df in pyspark:

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----+----------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|  ncf|      date|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+----------+------+
|    James|          |       V|36636|2021-09-03|  3000| remove
|  Michael|      Rose|        |40288|2021-09-10|  4000|
|   Robert|          |Williams|42114|2021-08-03|  4000|
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|39192|2021-05-13|  4000|
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|     |2020-09-03|    -1|
|    James|          |   Smith|36636|2021-09-03|  3000| remove
|    James|          |   Smith|36636|2021-09-04|  3000|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+----------+------+
```

I need remove rows where ncf and date were equal. The df result will be:

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----+----------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|  ncf|      date|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+----------+------+
|  Michael|      Rose|        |40288|2021-09-10|  4000|
|   Robert|          |Williams|42114|2021-08-03|  4000|
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|39192|2021-05-13|  4000|
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|     |2020-09-03|    -1|
|    James|          |   Smith|36636|2021-09-04|  3000|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+----------+------+
```

Comment: Have you tried Distinct() on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to count if there are two or more rows with your conditions

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W


df.withColumn('duplicated', F.count('*').over(W.partitionBy('ncf', 'date').orderBy(F.lit(1))) > 1)

# +---------+----------+--------+-----+----------+------+----------+
# |firstname|middlename|lastname|  ncf|      date|salary|duplicated|
# +---------+----------+--------+-----+----------+------+----------+
# |      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|     |2020-09-03|    -1|     false|
# |    James|          |       V|36636|2021-09-03|  3000|      true|
# |    James|          |   Smith|36636|2021-09-03|  3000|      true|
# |  Michael|      Rose|        |40288|2021-09-10|  4000|     false|
# |   Robert|          |Williams|42114|2021-08-03|  4000|     false|
# |    James|          |   Smith|36636|2021-09-04|  3000|     false|
# |    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|39192|2021-05-13|  4000|     false|
# +---------+----------+--------+-----+----------+------+----------+
```

You now can use `duplicated` to filter rows as desired.

Answer (score 1):

[dropDuplicates](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates.html)  method helps with removing duplicates with in a subset of columns.

```
df.dropDuplicates(['ncf', 'date'])
```

Comment: I didn't know `dropDuplicates` exists, so good to know! However OP wants to remove **both rows**, so in this case `dropDuplicates` wouldn't work